# Is there a way to "rotate" Grafana charts?

Tags: grafana, reporting, dashboard, influxdb

I'm working with Grafana and I would like to "rotate" a chart, so that the time axis will be on the Y-Axis and the values-by-time will show on the X-axis.
Here's an image of the desired effect, hope it's clear.

[Values_vs_time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLAOQ.png)

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Thank you!
D